# Как cделать появление элемента на время при движении мыши?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать видео плеер, но не знаю как сделать что бы управление появлялось при движении мыши. Вот допустим ютуб, вот там при движении мыши появляется управление, но не как не могу найти как это делать. Перелопатил всё, но нашел только про ховер. Кто может, помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: А пробовали `mousemove`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show hide controls:

```
var timeout_controls;

function set_timeout_controls() {
    if ($('.video_controls').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.video_controls').css('display', 'block');
        $('.your_element').css('cursor', 'default');
    }

    clearTimeout(timeout_controls);

    timeout_controls = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('.video_controls').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('.video_controls').css('display', 'none');
            $('.your_element').css('cursor', 'none');
        }
    }, 3000);
}

$(document).on('mousemove', '.your_element', function (e) {
    set_timeout_controls();
});
```